# Implement a variation of the IOTA Tangle?

Tags: iota-network, tangle

I'm a newbie on the IOTA Tangle, I understood the main functionalities and read the documentation regarding the different implementations. I'd like to know if exist some libraries allowing you to implement your own application ( with specific business logic) running upon the Tangle data structure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your application on Tangle easily.

There are various libraries and examples to help you through that. For detailed information on each please follow the [IOTA Wiki](https://wiki.iota.org/).

Specially, take a look at these projects:

1. [IOTA Streams](https://wiki.iota.org/streams/welcome)
2. [DID](https://wiki.iota.org/identity.rs/introduction)
3. [Wallet Lib](https://wiki.iota.org/wallet.rs/welcome)
4. [Client Libraries](https://wiki.iota.org/iota.rs/getting_started/required_prior_knowledge)
5. [IOTA Smart Contracts](https://wiki.iota.org/smart-contracts/overview)